# Jquery Change icon on popup save button

Tags: jquery

My goal is to change comment icon. When popup save button click.

My Html :

```
<input type="text" value="3" name="data_1[]" class="txtfld cell-input">
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="color_comment" href="#myModalMon_1"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalMon_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Comment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea name="data_1[]" rows="7" cols="37">Data of Teaxtarea</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" onclick="save('myModalMon_1')" class="btn btn-round btn-success commentSave">Save</button>
          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-round btn-default commentCancel" type="button">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="3" name="data_1[]" class="txtfld cell-input">
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="color_comment" href="#myModalTue_1"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalTue_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Comment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea name="data_1[]" rows="7" cols="37">Data of Teaxtarea</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" onclick="save('myModalTue_1')" class="btn btn-round btn-success commentSave">Save</button>
          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-round btn-default commentCancel" type="button">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have group of html code but when i click save button only it's commant icon change. right now it's not working.

My jquery:

```
function save(id){
  $('.color_comment').find('i').removeClass('fa-comment-o').addClass('fa-comments');
}
```

This jquery code apply of all html element.

Comment: try `$('#'+ id).prev().find('i').removeClass('fa-comment-o').addClass('fa-comments');`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you for quick response, it's working. Please add it as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$('#'+ id).prev().find('i').removeClass('fa-comment-o').addClass('fa-comments');`

`$('#'+ id)` refers to example `<div class="modal fade" id="myModalMon_1">` and then use `.prev()` to select the link, and then your code `.find('i').removeClass('fa-comment-o').addClass('fa-comments')` to find and do something with the `i`

Comment: @WebRence No problem, happy to help